# ElasticSearch geo_shape mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, geospatial, geojson

i do some mapping to my ES type with this command

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/lbs/road5/_mapping' -d '
{
    "properties": {
         "location": {
             "type": "geo_shape",
             "tree": "quadtree",
             "precision": "1m"
         }
    }
}
```

but when I insert with some source, my ES gives a warning like this

```
[2014-03-25 10:12:05,754][DEBUG][action.index             ] [Shadowcat] [lbs][4], node[Vtad6yMTQua7oOtIPaRtKg], [P], s[STARTED]: Failed to execute [index {[lbs][road5][4625611], source[{"osm_id":4625611,"osm_type":"residential","name":"sindang sirana elok","location":{"type":"linestring","coordinates":[[[107.5891297,-6.877704],[107.5891175,-6.8784478]]]}}]}]
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: failed to parse [location]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.geo.GeoShapeFieldMapper.parse(GeoShapeFieldMapper.java:244)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.serializeObject(ObjectMapper.java:517)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.parse(ObjectMapper.java:459)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:515)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:462)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.prepareIndex(InternalIndexShard.java:392)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:203)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.performOnPrimary(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:556)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$1.run(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:426)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.elasticsearch.common.geo.builders.BaseLineStringBuilder.decompose(BaseLineStringBuilder.java:90)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.geo.builders.BaseLineStringBuilder.decompose(BaseLineStringBuilder.java:71)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.geo.builders.BaseLineStringBuilder.build(BaseLineStringBuilder.java:55)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.geo.GeoShapeFieldMapper.parse(GeoShapeFieldMapper.java:231)
    ... 11 more
```

What's wrong with my document source?

```
{
  "osm_id": 4625611,
  "osm_type": "residential",
  "name":"sindang sirana elok",
  "location": {
    "type": "linestring",
    "coordinates": [
      [[107.5891297, -6.877704], [107.5891175, -6.8784478]]
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `linestring` has an extra array level in the `coordinates`. Try changing it to

```
{
  "osm_id": 4625611,
  "osm_type": "residential",
  "name":"sindang sirana elok",
  "location": {
    "type": "linestring",
    "coordinates": [
      [107.5891297, -6.877704], [107.5891175, -6.8784478]
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Note: this is so in order to match the geojson standard http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#id3, it is useful to avoid conversions, but is also not very intuitive for beginners

Comment: Agreed. Whoever came up with the GeJSON spec made a decision that goes against what most people do with lat/ long data in the interest of being super generic (for better or worse).